# How to get the service provider Id from a connected app of SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, identity, identity-provider

We have service provider id in Salesforce which looks something like this - '0sp3I0000004CN4'
This is used in the IdP-Initiated Login URL.
Here is the documentation for that: [IdP-Initiated Login URL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm)

Question is how can we get this 0sp Id in Salesforce for a connected App?

Official doc says '*You can use the service provider app ID with the app parameter in the following format. This value is displayed in the Salesforce user interface. From Setup, enter Connected Apps in the Quick Find box, then select Connected Apps, then click the name of the connected app to see its detail page.*'

https://<Salesforce_base_URL>/idp/login?app=<app_id>

But I didn't find it here. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @identigral- Here IDP is Salesforce's Portal Site and the login page of portal has some existing cusomization that whenever the login happens with IDP URL, instead of redirecting user to service provider, it redirects user to Portal Home page. For one of the service provider, we want to stick with default behavior that is when IDP login happens, navigate to the service provider. So, for this conditional logic I wanted to check the SP ID during the login. Is it possible to get the SP id for that particular SSO connected app?

Comment: The ID of the SP is available from the Connected App "manage" page in SAML Login Information section. There's a For Communities subpanel in this section, it's collapsed by default.

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much!